# ¿Cómo usar xquery para obtener el título de aquellos los libros que hayan tenido alguna venta el 2020 o 2021?

Tags: xml, xquery

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio de lenguaje de marcas y nos piden este ejercicio.

> ejemplo de xquery (: 1. Obtener el título de aquellos libros que hayan tenido alguna venta entre el 2020 y el 2021. :)

Sé encontrar los libros que hayan tenido alguna venta, pero no sé encontrar los libros que hayan tenido alguna venta entre los años indicados.

```
for $book in //book, $sale in //sale
where $book/title = $sale/refbook
return $book/author/data
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="COOKING">
<title>Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="WEB"
      soldout="true">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<year>2001</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="COOKING"
      soldout="true">
<title lang="en">Learning Cake</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
<ebook format="epub" />
</book>
<sale ident="v00001">
<refbook>Learning Cake</refbook>
<date>2021-11-30</date>
</sale>
<sale ident="v00002">
<refbook>XQuery Kick Start</refbook>
<date>2020-12-05</date>
</sale>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For $venta in doc("Bookstore.xml")/bookstore/sale 
Where contains($venta/date,"2020") Or ($venta/date,"2021") Return $venta/refbook
```

Al parecer esto podría servir

Answer (score 0):

La consulta de la primera respuesta podría no funcionar si no invocas la función contains() la segunda vez, de la manera siguiente:

```
for $venta in doc("Bookstore.xml")/bookstore/sale 
where contains($venta/date,"2020") or contains($venta/date,"2021") 
return $venta/refbook
```

Una manera alternativa de llegar a la misma solución es esta:

```
for $sale in /bookstore/sale
where $sale/date >= xs:date("2020-01-01") and $sale/date <= xs:date("2021-12-31")
return
  let $bookTitle := $sale/refbook
  return
    /bookstore/book[title = $bookTitle]/title/text()
```

Ambas soluciones asumen que los requisitos de la query son encontrar los libros vendidos entre los años 2020 y 2021, ambos **inclusive**.

Ten presente que estas comparaciones de los valores mayores o menores que la fecha en el documento solo son posibles gracias a que la fecha está expresada en el formato común anglosajón YYYY-mm-dd. Si se utilizasen fechas en el formato dd-mm-YYYY habitual en países hispanohablantes, lo mejor sería recurrir a la función contains() u otra alternativa.

He modificado un poco el documento XML original que subiste añadiendo otro registro de venta con una fecha fuera del rango de los libros que deberían ser recuperados, para someter mejor a prueba la consulta.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
   <book category="COOKING">
      <title>Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
   </book>
   <book category="WEB" soldout="true">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <author>James McGovern</author>
      <year>2001</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
   </book>
   <book category="COOKING" soldout="true">
      <title lang="en">Learning Cake</title>
      <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>39.95</price>
      <ebook format="epub" />
   </book>
   <sale ident="v00001">
      <refbook>XQuery Kick Start</refbook>
      <date>2020-12-05</date>
   </sale>
   <sale ident="v00002">
      <refbook>Learning Cake</refbook>
      <date>2021-11-30</date>
   </sale>
      <sale ident="v00003">
      <refbook>Everyday Italian</refbook>
      <date>2022-07-31</date>
   </sale>
</bookstore>
```